Type incompatibility warning with ToggleGroup component
I'm using a shadcnui ToggleGroup component in my Next js 14 project, and I'm running into a type incompatibility issue when trying to specify the type property as either "single" or "multiple". The ToggleGroup component seems to only accept "multiple", and I get the following error:
Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
  Type '"single" | "multiple"' is not assignable to type '"multiple"'.
    Type '"single"' is not assignable to type '"multiple"'.(2322)

Here's a simplified version of my code:
import React from 'react';
import { ToggleGroup, ToggleGroupItem } from '@/components/ui/toggle-group';

interface ToggleGroupComponentProps {
  label: string;
  options: Record<string, string>;
  type: 'single' | 'multiple';
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
}

const ToggleGroupComponent: React.FC<ToggleGroupComponentProps> = ({
  label,
  options,
  type,
  onChange,
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="mb-6">
      <label className="block text-gray-700 text-md font-bold mb-2">
        {label}
      </label>
      <ToggleGroup
        className="p-0 flex flex-wrap items-start justify-start"
        type={type}
        size="lg"
        onValueChange={onChange}
      >
        {Object.entries(options).map(([key, value]) => (
          <ToggleGroupItem
            variant="outline"
            key={key}
            value={key}
            className="mr-2 mb-2 bg-orange-100 text-sky-950"
          >
            {value}
          </ToggleGroupItem>
        ))}
      </ToggleGroup>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ToggleGroupComponent;

And the usage in the Home component:
'use client';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import ToggleGroupComponent from '@/components/ToggleGroupComponent';

const FruitPreferences = {
  APPLE: 'Apple',
  BANANA: 'Banana',
  ORANGE: 'Orange',
  GRAPE: 'Grape',
};

const ExerciseTypes = {
  YOGA: 'Yoga',
  RUNNING: 'Running',
  SWIMMING: 'Swimming',
  CYCLING: 'Cycling',
};

const HobbyChoices = {
  READING: 'Reading',
  PAINTING: 'Painting',
  GARDENING: 'Gardening',
  COOKING: 'Cooking',
  MEDITATION: 'Some Meditation Technique',
};

export default function Home() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    fruitPreference: '',
    exerciseType: '',
    hobbyChoice: '',
  });

  const handleToggleChange = (label: string, value: string) => {
    setFormData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [label]: value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    console.log(formData);
  };

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <div className="bg-gray-200">
        <section className="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-2">
          <div className="container mx-auto max-w-6xl flex flex-col justify-start mt-12">
            <h3 className="text-2xl text-gray-800 mb-8">Preferences</h3>
            <ToggleGroupComponent
              label="Fruit Preference"
              options={FruitPreferences}
              type="multiple"
              onChange={(value: string) =>
                handleToggleChange('fruitPreference', value)
              }
            />
            <ToggleGroupComponent
              label="Exercise Type"
              options={ExerciseTypes}
              type="multiple"
              onChange={(value: string) =>
                handleToggleChange('exerciseType', value)
              }
            />
            <ToggleGroupComponent
              label="Hobby Choice"
              options={HobbyChoices}
              type="multiple"
              onChange={(value: string) =>
                handleToggleChange('hobbyChoice', value)
              }
            />

            <Button onClick={handleSubmit} className="mt-4">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-h3fytu?file=components%2FToggleGroupComponent.tsx
How can I resolve this type incompatibility warning  issue?

in shadcn  <ToggleGroup type="single"> type added to the ToggleGroup  component. here you are using it in the ToggleGroupItem

@DileepaMabulage I am using ,  <ToggleGroup className="p-0 flex flex-wrap items-start justify-start" type={type}

can to attach your sample options object

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-h3fytu?file=components%2FToggleGroupComponent.tsx see code here

@DileepaMabulage everything is in questions.

in your ToggleGroupComponentProps onChange define value as any
interface ToggleGroupComponentProps {
  label: string;
  options: Record<string, string>;
  type: 'single' | 'multiple';
  onChange: (value: any) => void;
}


seems that works i will test and get back to you
